# Spring Keycloak Adapter redirect to custom url

Tags: angular, spring-boot, keycloak

I'm building a `Spring Boot` application with `Angular` frontend.
To get a `JWT` from the backend, the frontend is calling a `REST` endpoint (`myapp/login` that will return the `JWT` as string). Since I'm not authenticated the `Spring Keycloak Adapter` redirects me to the login page. When I submit my credentials Keycloak redirects me back to the request URL (`myapp/login`).

The problem I'm facing is that if I get redirect to `myapp/login` the browser will simply display the returned JWT from the rest controller instead of redirect my to my `SPA`. But I want to display the SPA and get the fullfilled HttpRequest and not get redirected to the controller which outputs the token as string.

How can I alter the redirect url to get back to the SPA or how should handle this scenario?

This is my security config:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http.sessionManagement().enableSessionUrlRewriting(true)
    .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .accessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager)
            .expressionHandler(expressionHandler)
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
    .and()
        .logout().logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler())
    .and()
        .addFilterAfter(jwtTokenFilter, KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.class);
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the code please?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? Am facing the same issue currently